# DatePicker and CalendarView display more than one month on Android 21

Tags: android, android-datepicker

When using `DatePicker` or `CalendarView` in xml:

```
<DatePicker
    android:id="@+id/date_picker"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_4x"
    android:background="@drawable/background_calendar_view"
    android:elevation="@dimen/cardview_default_elevation"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/guideline_end"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/guideline_start"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

On Android 21 it looks like this:

[image]

It should displays only currently selected month - August, but it also displays September at the bottom.

On Android 23+ it looks ok:

[image]

You can only see August month (currently selected), which is correct.

What could be a problem?

Comment: I am not sure if I follow your question. Are you not able to change months by scrolling vertically, in API 21? Because, I can see September month right below August in that UI.

Comment: @Jar did you check two screenshots? that's the problem that it should not display September on Android 21, only currently selected month August

Comment: [Android 10 DatePicker layout](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/android10-release/core/res/res/layout/date_picker_material.xml) are designed differently than that of [Android Lollipop](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/lollipop-release/core/res/res/layout/date_picker_legacy.xml). It's implemented in AOSP widgets as such so you can't make it similar as you want. Maybe customize it in API 21?

Comment: You can also see that Android 10 has [DayPickerViewPager](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/android10-release/core/res/res/layout/day_picker_content_material.xml#22) while Android 5 has a [ListView](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/lollipop-release/core/java/android/widget/CalendarView.java#911) to show the months.

Comment: @Jay it works fine on 23 API too, Android 29 is not related... Only issue on 21 API. Nothing to customize here...

Comment: You did mention `Android 23+` in your question. What I mean is that starting from 23+ APIs, they have introduced new UI concept for these widgets that's why you can see different designs in API 21 and 23+. Android 29 inherits from 23 -- not everything but, at least in this case the layout structures for `DatePicker` and `CalenderView` widgets. Hope this helps!

Comment: @Jay I understand it has changed but this fact doesn't help to solve the problem